# Does the water change momentum?

Tags: momentum

I was doing a question that went like

> A boat hits the sandbank. The rower stands up and uses his oar to push the boat back into the water. The resulting change in momentum involved which of the following:
> the boat, the rower, the water, the earth

I thought it would be all 4, but the answers say all of them except the water.

The boat obviously experiences a change in momentum as it was still and now it moves. The rower was also still and now is moving away. The Earth should experience a change in momentum as the ore pushes against the Earth so it should move slightly. I also think that the water will experience a change in momentum because if you imagine the boat being invisible, initially the water was still and now it would all be flowing in one direction with the boat.

Is the question wrong or does the water also experience a change in momentum?

Comment: The water would all be flowing in one direction with the boat?  I can't picture that.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm imagining the boat a a big wooden cube. If you push the block forward, the water infront of the wood would move forward. The water at the back would also move forward to fill the void (there might also be some swirling but I'll ignore that)

Comment: I think the question is unclear. Too much depends on the word "resulting". Judging by the answer, the question setter wants you to consider only the momentum given to the boat and rower by the Earth (and the momentum given to the Earth by the boat and rower. You are quite right that there will be momentum exchanges between the moving boat and the water, but the question setter wants you to ignore them. (S)he doesn't, imo, signal this clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking that the water will move along with the boat is because of **Viscous friction** between the water surface and the boat. Unless that is explicitly stated I supposed you should consider water still.

Now strictly speaking as long as nothing is mentioned about this friction in the question, I don't think you are wrong in assuming water also takes some momentum. (By the way, this depends on the context/place wheere the question is asked, if you are not taught about this friction or the chapter itself doesnt mention anthing of this sort, probably you too shouldnt consider it)

Answer (score 1):

When a body such as a boat moves in water, the water will in general aquire some momentum.  It is almost impossible to compute how *much* momentum, however. It depends on the shape of the boat, the shape of the body of water, how much of a bow wave is formed, and many other things.